# Angular Capacitor Mobile app not fetching data from server API

Tags: android, angular, android-studio, ionic-framework, capacitor

I have an Angular web app which I converted to a mobile app using Capacitor.
The web app works fine, but whenever I run the application using the Android Studio emulator I'm not able to fetch data from the API server which is hosted on localhost:5000 using a proxy.

Whenever I try to open google chrome on the emulator and type 10.0.2.2:5000 it connects to the API server and shows the data. But I don't want to use 10.0.2.2 as localhost.

I have also tried to edit the capacitor.config.ts like this. In this case, it works but whenever I click to go to the next page on the app it automatically redirects me to localhost:5000 and stops working.

```
server: {
    url: 'http://10.0.2.2:4300',
    hostname: '10.0.2.2',
    androidScheme: 'http',
    allowNavigation: [],
  },
```

This is the function that returns the data that I need to see:

```
this.authentication.getAuthnContexts().subscribe(data => {
  console.log(JSON.stringify(data)); //data is empty when running on android emulator
  this.authMode = data.contexts
});
```

And this is the observable which fetch the data from the server:

```
getAuthnContexts(): Observable<AuthMode>{
    console.log('prova console');
     //I append "http://localhost:5000" in front of the url from proxy.config.test.json
     return this.http.get<AuthMode>('api/authn/contexts').pipe(
     catchError(this.handleError<AuthMode>('getAuthnContexts', new AuthMode ))
   );
 }
```

The commands I'm using to run the app on the emulator are:

```
ng build
npx cap copy android
npx cap open android
```

In the AndroidManifest.xml I have already added the following line (not sure if it has something to do with the problem):

```
android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"
```

Answer (score 0):

localhost is “this device”, so when you run from your computer, it works because it’s running on the same machine where the server is.
But if you run in an emulator or real device, localhost is the device or emulator and there is no server running on them.

You have to use the local IP of the computer where the server is running, something like 192.168.1.xxx

Comment: Thanks for your response, but how should I tell my emulator device to use the IP address of my computer? Do I need to specify it in the capacitor.config.ts file as I did in my example? Or do I need to set it directly from android studio somehow?

Comment: It’s not a capacitor thing, it depends on how you connect your app to your API server. I guess it’s where you say      //I append "http://localhost:5000" in front of the url from proxy.config.test.json. There you have to use your local IP instead of localhost

Comment: go to your cmd type: `ipconfig` you will see your ip IPv4 that is your IP to use. this is for Windows.